# Memory usage of filter foo [2..n] !! 0

Tags: haskell, ghc

Suppose I have the following function

```
small_div :: Int -> Int
small_div n = filter (\x -> n `rem` x == 0) [2..n] !! 0
```

What's the memory usage of this function? The equivalent C code would be constant memory usage and I believe that Haskell's lazy evaluation means that it won't create more elements of [2..n] than are needed to find the first divisor, but is ghc smart enough to make the jump to something like...

```
int small_div(int n) {
    for (int x = 2; x <= n; x++) {
        if (n % x == 0) {
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not compile it and look at the resulting instructions in a disassembler?

Comment: Adding a simple main to get a number from the user, and print the result of calling small_div creates a 150,000 line objdump, which I can't understand well enough to get the answer.

Comment: FYI, the answer probably depends on what version of GHC you run. 7.10 probably gives you a better chance of getting C-like performance in this particular case, but I haven't tried.

Comment: `ghc --version` says I'm on 7.6.3.

Comment: By the way, you should think about ways to improve your algorithm. This one kind of stinks :P. You can improve performance much more by improving the algorithm than by fussing with micro-optimizations in this case.

Comment: @dfeuer: Yeah, I realize the efficient way is to check the primes <= sqrt(n) and if that fails return [n],

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC 7.10 and 7.8.4 (the versions I tested) are smart enough to make the jump to your optimized example.

I looked up two primes from the internet, 15485863 and 67867967. When I compiled and ran `main = print $ small_div 15485863` with `+RTS -s` flag, my total heap allocation was 51 Kb. When I ran the same with 67867967, I got 51 Kb allocation as well. This implies that no cells were allocated for the generation and filtering of the list.

It was very likely optimized by the so-called [`foldr/build`](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/build.md) fusion (`filter` and `enumFromTo` for `Int`-s both participate in this kind of fusion).

Answer (score 3):

For looking at the results of GHC's high-level optimizations, a better option than assembler output is GHC's internal core language after the simplifier phase.
It does take a bit to learn to read but should be much shorter than the assembly.  I'm only a beginner in understanding core but let me try to show a bit.

Oh, and since I'm using the Haskell Platform, this is with GHC 7.8.3.

Given the file

```
module Test where

small_div :: Int -> Int
small_div n = filter (\x -> n `rem` x == 0) [2..n] !! 0
```

If we compile with *no* optimization option, and dump the core input with all
"extra" information suppressed (this removes a *lot* of analysis and type information, leaving only the essential structure):

```
ghc -dsuppress-all -ddump-simpl Test.hs
```

we get the definition as

```
small_div =
  \ n_apH ->
    !!
      (filter
         (\ x_arI -> == $fEqInt (rem $fIntegralInt n_apH x_arI) (I# 0))
         (enumFromTo $fEnumInt (I# 2) n_apH))
      (I# 0)
```

which is basically the Haskell directly translated into core, still containing all list construction.  The syntax of core is much simpler than Haskell, even operators are used prefix. On the other hand a lot of internal GHC details are now peeking out, such as the `I#` constructor for `Int` and the `$fEqInt` monomorphic function for comparing `Int`s.

Note that even in this form, laziness and garbage collection *should* mean that it will be able to run in constant space, probably (meaning I'm "educatedly" guessing here) staying entirely within GHC's highly efficient GC "nursery" generation for short-lived data.

Now if we add the `-O` basic optimization option to GHC the output gets a *lot* trickier (and even worse with `-O2`). `filter` and `enumFromTo` both disappear, having been removed by the list fusion optimizations and the results being inlined. Also most of the arithmetic now works on unboxed `Int#`s.  Here is the `-O` output in all its glory:

```
small_div2
small_div2 = I# (-1)

small_div1
small_div1 = !!_sub ([]) 0

$wsmall_div
$wsmall_div =
  \ ww_s1dD ->
    case tagToEnum# (># 2 ww_s1dD) of _ {
      False ->
        letrec {
          a_s1e8
          a_s1e8 =
            case ww_s1dD of _ {
              __DEFAULT -> go_a1ch 0;
              (-1) -> []
            };
          lvl_s1e1
          lvl_s1e1 = : small_div2 a_s1e8;
          go_a1ch
          go_a1ch =
            \ x_a1ci ->
              case x_a1ci of wild1_a1aq {
                __DEFAULT ->
                  case remInt# ww_s1dD wild1_a1aq of _ {
                    __DEFAULT ->
                      case tagToEnum# (==# wild1_a1aq ww_s1dD) of _ {
                        False -> go_a1ch (+# wild1_a1aq 1);
                        True -> []
                      };
                    0 ->
                      : (I# wild1_a1aq)
                        (case tagToEnum# (==# wild1_a1aq ww_s1dD) of _ {
                           False -> go_a1ch (+# wild1_a1aq 1);
                           True -> []
                         })
                  };
                (-1) -> lvl_s1e1;
                0 -> case divZeroError of wild2_00 { }
              }; } in
        !!_sub (go_a1ch 2) 0;
      True -> small_div1
    }

small_div
small_div =
  \ w_s1dA ->
    case w_s1dA of _ { I# ww1_s1dD -> $wsmall_div ww1_s1dD }
```

However, even after all this fusion and inlining, it still contains the `:` list constructor in places.  And note the single line in there, giving the usual final result of the largest function:

```
        !!_sub (go_a1ch 2) 0;
```

The construction of the outer list, and the `!! 0` indexing of it are *not* being optimized away. (Although I'm not including `-O2` output, the same still holds for it.)

Nevertheless, the intermediate `[2..n]` list *is* gone, meaning that, if my understanding is correct, laziness will ensure that this function will allocate at most a single list cell.